# In Unity how to make a public float or int variable not be able to have a negative input by the user

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently in the process of putting some Assets in the Unity Asset store and as I was going over displaying errors made by the user for inputs for public variables.  One of them is them being able to choose the camera width and height and I do not want them to have the option to put in a negative number. The closest thing I could find was [Range(x,y)] but then this changes my variable input in the inspector to a slider which I do not want.

I know I can always just check if its negative through code and then tell the user through Debug but I feel if I don't even let the user place negative numbers in the first place this will save a check and less code.

Anyone have any ideas or am I basically stuck with checking and letting them know through Debug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OnValidate` is the MonoBehaviour function that was created for this purpose. As the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) says: "This can be used to ensure that when you modify data in an editor that the data stays within a certain range." In your script, write

```
OnValidate()
{
    theValue = Mathf.Clamp(theValue, 0, float.MaxValue); // or int.MaxValue, if you need to use an int but can't use uint.
}
```

Comment: I never even knew this existed *FacePalm*.  Thank you poijo.

Comment: @JoeyL I think it's fairly new. Most people probably don't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.OnBeforeSerialize.html

Implement that interface then in your OnAfterDeserialize function do something like:

```
    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        cameraWidth = Mathf.Clamp(cameraWidth, 0, 99999);
    }
```

Alternatively put the clamp in your update loop and add [ExecuteInEditMode]. But that is not a good solution.

Comment: @JoeyL's answer is actually much better.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your data type as "uint" which is 32-bit unsigned integer type with the range of 0 to 4,294,967,295. This will not take negative values.

For floats, I am sorry there is nothing like uint, which accepts unsigned values. Either you have to take uint value from user and type cast it to float or you have to make a function to check if user has typed negative value and display a error. There might be other solutions also which I don't know, you have to keep looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScriptName : MonoBehaviour {
    //Variables

    public float floatName = 0;

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected () {
        if (floatName < 0) {
            floatName = 0;
        }
    }
}
```